# Python Web Scraping - Two Different Parent Class Names, Different Structures but same Child Class Names

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, parent-child

I'm trying to scrape the news articles from prnewswire.com. Each article is stored in a div called "row".
[image: Picture of this section HTML Code of prnewswire.com]

The problem for me is that some article previews have an image beside their title and description. Therefor under the "row"-classes it's either the class name "card" (with image) or "col-sm-12 card" (without image):
[image: Can be seen in this screenshot]

My current code is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

headers = {
    'User-Agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)' +
        'Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15'
}

articlelist = []


def getarticles(page):
    url = 'https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/news-releases-list/?page=' + str(page) + '&pagesize=100'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

prnewswire_articles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-sm-12 card'})

for item in prnewswire_articles:
    prnewswire_article = {
        'page': page,
        'article_title': item.find('h3').text,
        'article_link': 'https://www.prnewswire.com/' +
                        item.find('a')['href'],
        'article_description': item.find('p').text,
    }
    articlelist.append(prnewswire_article)
return

for x in range(1, 3):
    getarticles(x)

df = pandas.DataFrame(articlelist)
print(df.head())
print(len(df))
df.to_excel('PRNewsWire.xlsx', index=False)
print('Finished.')
```

I have discovered the following: In the line where I declare "prnewswire_articles" and look for a div with a certain class name, I get the results I want with the class "col-sm-12 card". But "card" or "row" doesn't work.

I noticed that the html structure of "card" classes is different to "col-sm-12 card" classes, but they both contain one "h3" element (the article's title), one "a href" and one "p" element [image: Can be seen here]

This is the error message I get when using "row" or "card" as class name:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/projectname/prnewswire.py", line 33, in <module>
    getarticles(x)
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/projectname/prnewswire.py", line 24, in getarticles
    'article_title': item.find('h3').text,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I've searched a whole day and didn't find anything. Just recently started learning Python, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid mistake, but I am at the end of finding an answer. Would really appreciate help a lot! :)

Comment: FYI "scrapping" means throwing away, as you do with rubbish. The correct term is __scraping__.

Comment: Oh, oversaw that, sorry. Was already changed when I wanted to edit it. English is only my second language, didn't know it better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all `.row` that are under class `.card-list` (using a [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)). I also changed how you extract the article title (just get the text following `<small>` element):

```
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)' +
        'Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15'
}

articlelist = []


def getarticles(page):
    url = 'https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/news-releases-list/?page=' + str(page) + '&pagesize=100'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    prnewswire_articles = soup.select('.card-list > .row')    # <-- select all rows that are under class "card-list"

    for item in prnewswire_articles:
        prnewswire_article = {
            'page': page,
            'article_title': item.select_one('h3 small').find_next_sibling(text=True).strip(),   # <--- select text that is after <small> element
            'article_link': 'https://www.prnewswire.com/' +
                            item.find('a')['href'],
            'article_description': item.find('p').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'),
        }
        articlelist.append(prnewswire_article)

for x in range(1, 3):
    getarticles(x)

df = pandas.DataFrame(articlelist)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
...

186     2  Wugen Announces Exclusive Partnership Agreemen...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/wuge...  Wugen Inc., a clinical-stage biotechnology com...
187     2  Upstryve Initiates Mentor Network for Trade St...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/upst...  Upstryve Inc (Upstryve) www.upstryve.com. Upst...
188     2  Inkling Simplifies Integration to Learning and...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/inkl...  Inkling, a global leader in digital learning p...
189     2  CommerceHub to Participate in Bank of America'...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/comm...  CommerceHub, a leading provider of ecommerce s...
190     2        Instrument Promotes Kara Place to President  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/inst...  Instrument, a digitally focused, creative agen...
191     2   Regent Properties Announces Executive Promotions  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/rege...  Regent Properties ("Regent"), a real estate in...
192     2  PowerPay Hits $1 Billion in Home Renovations L...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/powe...  PowerPay, the nation's fastest-growing home im...
193     2  GoldenTree Announces Closing of $698 Million C...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/gold...  GoldenTree Loan Management II ("GLM II") and i...
194     2  The Real-Time Moving Show on the Screen "Showt...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/the-...  EnableWow (www.showtap.com) launched a new pre...
195     2  Black Knight: Lock Activity Suggests Q1 2021 R...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/blac...  Today, the Data & Analytics division of Black ...
196     2  LG Innotek Joins Hands with Microsoft to Proli...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/lg-i...  LG Innotek (CEO Cheoldong Jeong) announced on ...
197     2  MicroWorkers Integrates Ontology's ONTO Wallet...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/micr...  To bridge micro workers globally, Ontology and...
198     2     MemVerge Introduces M3 Channel Partner Program  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/memv...  MemVerge™, the pioneers of Big Memory software...
199     2  Innovative Deals Spur the Growth of New Sports...  https://www.prnewswire.com//news-releases/inno...  Last year has shaped up to be crucial for the ...
```

Comment: Can't say more other than thank you. It worked. You can't believe how much time and energy you've saved me <3